# is there a similar command like "Invoke-AzVMRunCommand"(from azure) for gcp?

Tags: azure, shell, google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I am wondering if there is a way ,I can execute scripts on **GCP** vms from cloud shell.Like **Invoke-AzVMRunCommand** where its possible to run scripts from cloud shell on azure virtual machines

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud PowerShell is not as well implemented as in AWS and Azure. AFAIK there is no equivalent command.

You can duplicate the functionality of Invoke-AzVMRunCommand using PowerShell SSH features. This works out of the box with Linux systems. Windows requires [installing the OpenSSH server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1#msi), which is provided by Microsoft.

[PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1)